# Android - Resize parent and child view using layoutparams

Tags: android, android-layout, zooming, android-view, layoutparams

Hello I've a custom view that can be resized and the view have many child inside it

what I want to ask is how to resize the parent and the child together using layout params? how  to do that? I already tried to get the width of the view using `view.getWidth` and `view.getHeight` but it always return zero so I cannot scale it, and how can the child view can be resized in same scale as the parent?

I hope my question is clear enough but if you need some other explanation please leave it in the comment and I'll edit my question.

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you want to increase the bounds of the parent view and have child views grow in proportion? Like if the parent were 100x100 and the child was a 300x300 image, and when you increase the parent bounds the child image increases in size to fill the parent?

Comment: @BrettDuncavage Yes something like that, like if I the parent size is 1000x1000 dip and the child is 300x300dip image when I scale the parent with factor of 1.5 the parent size fill be 1500x1500dip and the child size will be 450x450dip is it possible? thanks

Comment: Well, without knowing what your layout code looks like, my guess is that setting the `android:scaleType` property on your child `ImageView` to `centerInside` might work (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

So when the bounds of the parent change the bounds of the child would change and image would scale. That is assuming you are not using absolute values for the `ImageView` width and height.

Comment: @BrettDuncavage ah sorry I forgot to mention my layout is an linear layout with many linear layout inside :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void resizeChildren(ViewGroup parent, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    // size is in pixels so make sure you have taken device display density into account
    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View v = parent.getChildAtIndex(i);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ((ViewGroup)v).LayoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Call the above method when the parent's bounds have changed and pass the parent into it. All children that are `ViewGroup` types will be resized. You could potentially call this recursively on each child as well if needed. You may have to call `requestLayout()` on the parent after resizing the children.

Comment: OK brett thanks for the idea! even your code didn't fully work but I got the idea thank you!

Comment: If you give me more information like posting your layout code, I could tailor this answer to be more complete.

Comment: ah the code quite complicated because of many custom view so I posted the code in the gist -> https://gist.github.com/NAYOSO/5303055 please take a look at it if you have some time the problem I have now is to maintaining the same aspect ratio of the childview, now the size of each child will be different when zooming thanks

Answer (score -1):

using this code you can resize parent and child by using the LayoutParams ...

```
LinearLayout header;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams headerParam;

header = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topheaderimage);
headerParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 100);
TextView headertext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
header.addView(headerimage, headerParam);
```

Comment: ah sorry but I'm adding the children programatically and I have many children so what do you think about it?generate and set an unique id to each children?

Comment: You can traverse the entire view hierarchy using the `ViewGroup.getChildCount()` and `ViewGroup.getChildAt(index)` methods. So there's no need for the `findViewById()` calls. Simply enumerate all the children of the parent and resize them.

Comment: @BrettDuncavage ah you give me a new idea! why don't you create your own answer and if it's work I can upvote and accept your answer? thanks!